# Unable to load Swagger UI "swagger.js:744 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$ref' of undefined"

Tags: rest, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have auto generated Swagger json docs (using jaxrs-analyzer plugin).When i try to load UI, Im getting
following error.

```
swagger.js:744 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$ref' of undefined
```

In the json i have,complex array type defined. (It is valid json)

```
 {
        "type" : "array",
        "description" : "xx",
        "uniqueItems" : true,
        "paramType" : "query",
        "name" : "grade"

}

"contactDetails" : {
          "type" : "array",
          "items" : {
            "$ref" : "ContactDetail"
          },
          "uniqueItems" : true
        },
```

How can I sort out this error?

```
<swagger-jaxrs-2-10-version>1.3.12</swagger-jaxrs-2-10-version>
        <swagger-annotations-version>1.5.3-M1</swagger-annotations-version>



<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-service-docs</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <doclet>com.carma.swagger.doclet.ServiceDoclet</doclet>
                            <docletArtifact>
                                <groupId>com.carma</groupId>
                                <artifactId>swagger-doclet</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0.4.1</version>
                            </docletArtifact>
                            <reportOutputDirectory>src/main/webapp</reportOutputDirectory>
                            <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
                            <additionalparam>-apiVersion 1 -docBasePath
                                /testdbwar/apidocs
                                -apiBasePath /testwar/rest
                                -swaggerUiPath
                                ${project.build.directory}/
                            </additionalparam>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>javadoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                </executions>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sebastian-daschner</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxrs-analyzer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>analyze-jaxrs</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Available backends, defaults to plaintext -->
                            <!-- <backend>plaintext</backend> -->
                            <backend>swagger</backend>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/apidocs</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>classes/**/*</include>
                                <include>testwar/**/*</include>
                                <include>**/*.war</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

**Edit;**

I have a get Method in my pojo like; (same like i have several get methods)

```
@JsonIgnore
    public Set<HistoryTankSystem> getHistoryStatusSet() {
        return historyStatusSet;
    }
```

Then in the json i get ;

```
"historyStatusSet" : {
          "type" : "array",
          "items" : {
            "$ref" : "HistoryTankSystem"
          },
          "uniqueItems" : true
        }
      },
```

This causes above issue issue.

And In the json i see it generates 1.2 definition;

```
{
  "apiVersion" : "1",
  "swaggerVersion" : "1.2",
  "basePath" : "/testwar/rest",
  "resourcePath" : "/TankSystems",
  "apis" : [ {
```

Comment: Could you post the complete JSON generated by the JAX-RS Analyzer? In which context is the `contactDetails` object included? It would be interesting to see where the output doens't follow the [Swagger 2.0 Definitions](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md).

Comment: @SebastianDaschner I have edited my question..

Comment: @SebastianDaschner this is a related another SO que http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339941/jsonignore-is-not-working-in-the-swagger-json-generation-when-using-jaxrs-analy

Comment: The JSON `{... "swaggerVersion":...}` is apparently generated from the swagger-doclet but not from the JAX-RS Analyzer. The tool never had other Swagger Versions in the Backend than 2.0.