# @JsonIgnore is not working in the Swagger JSON generation when using jaxrs-analyzer

Tags: json, annotations, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using [jaxrs-analyzer](https://github.com/sdaschner/jaxrs-analyzer) to generate Swagger JSON docs. In my POJO classes I have added `@JsonIgnore` annotation to skip them in the JSON doc, but I still see that portion in my swagger JSON doc, which then causes the following issue when loading Swagger UI:

> swagger.js:744 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$ref' of undefined`

```
@JsonIgnore
public Set<HistoryTankSystem> getHistoryStatusSet() {
    return historyStatusSet;
}

"historyStatusSet" : {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "$ref": "HistoryTankSystem"
    },
    "uniqueItems": true
}
```

Comment: Maybe related: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1595

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen The solution they mentioned in the thread too not working :(

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381492/jsonignore-apimodelpropertyhidden-true-xmltransient-none-are-working-in-s